# Track Postgres database activity caused by a single PHP script invocation

Tags: php, logging, monitoring, psql, postgresql-9.3

Is it possible to track database activity from the beginning, until the end of a PHP script invocation?

For example, let's say I have a script which creates a new record for a user in a database. You fill in a form, hit submit and provided all the data is valid the script proceeds to affect multiple tables inserting data.

The script inserts data into a main user table; (name, address, tel, etc...) is returned a new userid and then also adds a record to a department table (userid, departmentid) and a salary amount to a payroll table (userid, salary).

Is there a way to see all the tables that were affected by the script, the order in which they were used and the data passed to them for a single invocation?

Extra info: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Apache 2.4.7, PHP 5.5.9 and Postgres 9.3.5. I am the sole user of this machine; Everything will be run locally.

Ultimately I want to set the script running and watch what it does in the Postgres DB.

Thank you.

Comment: What I would do is add some kind of SQL Logger in your script that captures all queries submitted to the database. The logger takes the queries, stores them and then sends the query to the database to be executed. I am not very familar with postgres but there may be an auditing utility. But it would likely only show a connection id or something as the source of the query which wouldn't be very helpful as the DB doesnt care or track where queries are coming from

Comment: Yes @LuckyBurger, that's an option certainly - A colleague also suggested that I could run tail -f on the log file which might give some useful output too. I was trying to avoid dirtying my script with code that was irrelevant to the functionality though. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Yeah aside from adding that logging layer into your architecture I can't really think of any other way of doing it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this server-side, by setting `log_statement = 'all'` and setting a suitable `log_line_prefix` to include the backend process ID, transaction ID, etc.

You might find it useful to set an `application_name` in the client connection string or `SET application_name = 'blah'` in your script, so it's easier to find in the logs too.

Note that you can set `log_statement` on a per-user basis with `ALTER USER blah SET log_statement = 'all'`, or on a per-database basis with `ALTER DATABASE blah SET log_statement = 'all'`. You can clear the setting later with `ALTER ... RESET log_statement`.

Use of CSV format logs makes it easier too.

Comment: Thank you @craig-ringer, not only did this answer my immediate question, it also gave me insight into some of the other settings available to me for use with PostgreSQL and allowed me to isolate the logging for just one user which will be useful, especially if I had a problem with logging slowing down queries for other users. Thank you!